# How to pass int as rvalue argument to a function or constructor?

Tags: c++

In the following code the **class A** has 2 constructors, one taking int by value and the other taking int by rvalue reference. How to create an object using the second constructor call.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
  A(int i) : r_i(i)
  {
    cout<<endl<<"A(inti)";
  }

  A(int&& i) : r_i(i)
  {
    cout<<endl<<"A(int&&)";
  }

private:
  int &r_i;
};

int main()
{
  int j = 5;
  A a(j); // Works
  A b(std::move(j)); //  Error [1]
}
```

**Error [1] :**  call of overloaded ‘`A(std::remove_reference<int&>::type)`’ is ambiguous

Which c++ rule prevents the call to rvalue constructor ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overload resolution between object, rvalue reference, const reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17961719/overload-resolution-between-object-rvalue-reference-const-reference)

Comment: Duplicate of answered: [Ambiguous call with overloaded r-value reference function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28701039/ambiguous-call-with-overloaded-r-value-reference-function/31551595)

Comment: In the first ctor your reference becomes dangling, you know?